# Can You Add SKPhysicsBody To Only One Side Of A Rectangular Node?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

So let's say I have this rectangular SKNode. Can I add SKPhysicsBody to only one side of the rectangle i.e. only the top side, so that only the top side could detect collision and not the other sides (then the physics indicator blue line would only appear on the top and not anywhere else)?

I wanted to create a game, but I don't know whether something like this could work.

So if I could, how?

If I can't, is there a way around this issue?

I wanted to add a normal rectangle with physicsBody on only one side.

See the rectangle image here, the blue part is the place where I want the physicsBody

[image]

So I've tried adding an edgeBased physicsBody, but it doesn't seem to work (either the physicsBody didn't get created or it is in the wrong position).

```
let rectangle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Rectangle")
rectangle.size = CGSize(width: 128, height: 128)
rectangle.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
rectangle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeFrom: CGPoint(x: rectangle.position.x - rectangle.size.width/2, y: rectangle.position.y + rectangle.size.width/2), to: CGPoint(x: rectangle.position.x + rectangle.size.width/2, y: rectangle.position.y + rectangle.size.width/2))
rectangle.physicsBody!.restitution = 0.0
rectangle.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = physicsCategories.groundCategory
rectangle.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = physicsCategories.squareCategory
addChild(rectangle)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could, but it would also detect collision coming from the 'wrong' side i.e. with an object that has traveled through the node.

Physics bodies can be volume or edge based, but even an edge-based one that was only a pixel thick still has 4 sides.

If you could supply a drawing of *exactly* what you want, we could help better as there are probably several different approaches.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the help! I read the Apple documentation and tried it a few times, there is actually a physics body created, but I don't seem to get the position right.

Comment: I've also added a drawing

Comment: Thanks - I'll try a post a possible solution today